# Compose : advanceTimeBy doesn't work with animation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-animation, android-jetpack-compose-testing

I've two `Box`es and one `Button`. Clicking on the `Button` would toggle a flag and it triggers an `AnimatedVisibility` animation on these Boxes.

**Code**

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TestBox() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        var flag by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        AnimatedVisibility(
            visible = !flag,
            enter = slideInHorizontally(animationSpec = tween(3000)) { it },
            exit = slideOutHorizontally(animationSpec = tween(3000)) { -it }
        ) {
            // Red box
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(Color.Red)
                    .testTag("red_box"),
            ) {}
        }

        AnimatedVisibility(
            visible = flag,
            enter = slideInHorizontally(animationSpec = tween(3000)) { it },
            exit = slideOutHorizontally(animationSpec = tween(3000)) { -it }
        ) {
            // Red box
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(Color.Green)
                    .testTag("green_box"),
            ) {}
        }

        Button(onClick = { flag = !flag }) {
            Text(text = "TOGGLE")
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Now I want to write a test to check if two boxes are visible in the middle of the transition. So I wrote a test like this

```kotlin
class BoxAnimationTest {
    
    
    @get:Rule
    val composeRule = createComposeRule()

    @Before
    fun beforeAll() {
        composeRule.setContent {
            TestBox()
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun firstTest() {
        with(composeRule) {
            mainClock.autoAdvance = false
            onNodeWithTag("red_box").assertExists() // red box visible
            onNodeWithTag("green_box").assertDoesNotExist() // green box shouldn't be visible
            onNodeWithText("TOGGLE").performClick() // clicking toggle button
            
            mainClock.advanceTimeBy(1500) // and advance time to half of total duration (3000ms)
            onNodeWithTag("green_box").assertExists() // now both green and 
            onNodeWithTag("red_box").assertExists() // [FAILED] red should be visible
            
            mainClock.advanceTimeBy(1500) // finishing the animation
            onNodeWithTag("green_box") // now green should be visible
            onNodeWithTag("red_box").assertDoesNotExist() // but red shouldn't be
        }
    }
}
```

But it fails at `onNodeWithTag("red_box").assertExists()` (2nd).

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Failed: assertExists.
Reason: Expected exactly '1' node but could not find any node that satisfies: (TestTag = 'red_box')
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

> Some initial investigation showed that the animations from
> `AnimatedVisibility` were never added to the `Transition`, because
> `measure()` was not called and slide animation is initialized during
> measure. As a result, we ended up having an empty `Transition` that
> finished right away. That's why the test failed. Note that adding
> `advanceTimeByFrame()` before `advanceTimeBy(1500)` seems to allow the
> test to pass. This might be useful for narrowing down the cause.

- Source - KotlingLang Slack : https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/CJLTWPH7S/p1644036648038349?thread_ts=1643956469.612919&cid=CJLTWPH7S
- Issue Tracker : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/217880227